# DICOM Render not showing all slices (with possible fix)

Tags: xtk

I had 88 DICOM image importing into a 2D Render, but only 8 where showing.  Using Chrome's developer tools I was able to see that all data (88 slices) were loaded.  However, the V.MRI.pixdim was incorrect (reporting a slice thickness of 9+ where it was 1.5).  Tracked the area to parserDC.js line 95.  My locations were coming in as text, and when sorted as text were sorting wrong.  The below code seems to have solve my problem on a limited test basis:

```
MRI.location.sort(function{a,b} {return a-b; })
```

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update.

Can you share the anonymized data set so we can have a look?

Also, which version of XTK are you using?

Best

Comment: I'm using 0049a47726 (9/11/2013) from git.  I'll send the DICOMs via email once anonymized.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I pushed a fix https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox/1413c9969a22d890 .

Comment: In general, we recommend to use nii or nrrd file format as of now, since the file parsers are more robusts but it is defintly on our to do list to have a complete dcm parser. Thanks again

Comment: I can confirm it working with the un-anonymized data (git 5ae2d65).  Looks like there were several other items that went along with this fix.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes a few small modifications.
Btw, you could convert your stack of dicom images to nrrd or nii and the 2D slices would appear in the right orientation :)

Comment: Checkout the latest XTK, DICOM orientation should be correct now :)